# Write Conflict in Access using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

There are other question on this site that do go pretty close to what I'm about to ask, but mine is slightly different (if anyone knows of a question that exists that covers this problem exactly, then please guide me to it).

I have Windows Server 2003 which has SQL Server 2000 (I think) on it.  On that SQL Server, I have 5 databases, four of which I currently use.  Now, I also have a laptop(win xp pro) which has a copy of Enterprise Manager installed on it, and I maintain the SQL databases via the laptop, with no problems whatsoever (over the network inotherwords).

I also have on the laptop a 'frontend' in Access with an ODBC link, so that I can use forms in Access to view the contents of the tables in SQL.  I have had no problems with this setup for several weeks (since I created the databases in fact).

However, the problem I have with Access, is that I AM able to alter the information in two of the databases, but NOT the other two. When I try to make changes in either of the two NON working ones, I get a "write conflict - this record has been changed by another user...", however I am THE ONLY user!  I am using a SQL Server login, which I have to type in each time I open the Access frontend.  What is going on here?  I have read something about a timestamp field, but I don't understand why I might have to implement or indeed how to implement?  This issue is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

Do the tables you are amending have correct primary keys in the 2 databases which aren't working? The reason I ask is that if Access is unable to determine the exact record you are updating (due to lack of a primary key or other unique field) it will often give the 'Write Conflict' error. As you've mentioned, people often suggest timestamp fields when this issue occurs also, but in my experience this only helps when dealing with Access and MySQL, rather than SQL Server.

Also, which version (and service pack) of Access are you using?

Comment: ALL four tables have primary keys, not sure what you mean by 'correct' primary keys though.  I did have a problem with Access before though, where the forms in Access would appear blank with no fields in, until I created primary keys for the tables and it resolved the  problem.  I'm using Access 2000 (which yes I know it's not exactly up to date), however that's obviously not causing the problem, because why would it work for two of the tables and not the rest.  All the tables are under the same SQL server instance.

Comment: Also, the two tables that don't work have integer keys and the two that do have char keys.  Couldn't see it being an issue, but tested it by changing one of them from int to char, but didn't solve anthing, so changed it back.

Comment: Sorry, the word correct should NOT be there, I just meant primary keys. :) There are also issues with bit and float fields in Access 2000 and SQL Server ([link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280730)). Do either of those apply to the 2 tables causing the issue?

Comment: As it turns out the two problem tables DO have bit fields in them, HOWEVER, I just checked the last of the four tables (one of the ones that happens to be ok), and it also has bit fields in it.  So that doesn't appear to be the problem.  Damn, I thought you were onto something there.

Comment: And did you also check that the ones with bit fields that are causing the problem actually have a value in the bit field? You will need to check that from SQL Query Designer (rather than Access) using something like `SELECT * FROM <<TABLE_NAME>> WHERE <<BIT_FIELD>> IS NULL`. Provided you've checked that, you can also read about the SQL timestamp field [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx) and maybe think about trying to put that in the problem tables and re-linking in Access to see if it helps?

Comment: The null bits is a common issue. I would also add a timestamp to any table.

Comment: I think you've cracked it.  I've just checked, and it turns out that the last of the four tables I mentioned (which appeared to be ok), isn't.  In fact what's been happening is that the two tables that I said had problems, ALL the records in both of the tables have NULLs in the bit field, and that's why they won't work.  The last table, most of the records have NULL values in the bit fields, and those that don't, I AM able to alter the records, but the ones that DO, I get the error message.  So I only thought the last table wasn't faulty, because the records I was altering didn't have NULLs.

Comment: So it looks like I am going to have to change all the NULL values to zero for the time being to prevent further problems.  It's a shame that Microsoft couldn't have written a more useful error msg.  Thankyou for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! :)

Comment: @RichardC: very helpful answer.  It's the BIT columns with NULL which were causing the problem for me.  Didn't have to make the column NOT NULL, just populate with 0, and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any BIT fields, if you are doing an update on the table, you have to insert a value into the BIT fields, IE "0" into each field. They cannot be null.